# How to get multiple articles with specific ids via JSON:API in one request

Tags: http-request

how can I get multiple articles with specific ids in one request. I have tried lots of variations of `https://website.com/jsonapi/node/article/aecc1a8b-b827-46a5-956b-16feb49e47c9` but without success.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal's JSON:API implementation basically follows the [JSON:API Specification](https://jsonapi.org/format/), which is not specific to Drupal.

That means you don't need to include Drupal in search queries; a search for "jsonapi multiple ids" gave [this as the first result](https://discuss.jsonapi.org/t/fetching-multiple-resources-using-ids/1611):

```
filter[id]=1,2,3
```